# How can I Integrate native SDK in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-method-channel

I have to integrate native payment gateway in both android and iOS, how can I achieve this in flutter method channel? Any proper documentation for getting result from SDK after integration part?

Comment: Yes, the official Flutter documentation: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Answer (score 0):

Refer this medium article, this contain example native code for both platform, android and iOS.
[How to develop a platform channel in Flutter](https://medium.com/47billion/creating-a-bridge-in-flutter-between-dart-and-native-code-in-java-or-objectivec-5f80fd0cd713)